# sfUser equivalent in Symfony 2

Tags: symfony

What is the `sfUser` equivalent in Symfony 2?

`sfUser` allowed getting user session attributes using `getAttribute()` method.

Is `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User` its equivalent? But it doesn't have `getAttribute()` method in it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get session attributes, get the session service from the container.  This example is in a controller, where the session is available via a helper method:

```
public function fooAction()
{
    $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();

    // Setting
    $session->set("foo", "bar");

    // Retrieving
    $foo = $session->get("foo");
}
```

See the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#managing-the-session) for details.  You can also retrieve the session explicitly from the container should you need it, via `$container->get("session");`

If you need the User object, you can get it via:

```
public function fooAction()
{
    // Get user from security token (assumes logged in/token present)
    $user = $this->get("security.context")->getToken()->getUser();
}
```

Again, see the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#retrieving-the-user-object) for further details.